# Creation timestamp of a row in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, insert

Using SQLAlchemy ORM, what is a good way to record the creation time of a record, without overwriting the creation time on subsequent updates?

Here's a sample table definition:

```
class Car:
    model = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    latest_model_year = Column(Integer)
    created = Column(DateTime)
```

I would like to use this code to add/update a Car row in the database:

```
car = Car(
    model = 'Accord',
    latest_model_year = 2022,
)
session.merge(car)
```

... but that doesn't set the `created` column when a new row is inserted.

I could do something like this:

```
if session.query(Car).filter(Car.model=='Accord').first():
    # this car already exists, so update the existing row
    car = Car(
        model = 'Accord',
        latest_model_year = 2022,
    )
    session.merge(car)
else:
    # this car does not exist, so create a new row
    car = Car(
        model = 'Accord',
        latest_model_year = 2022,
        created = datetime.now(),
    )
    session.add(car)
```

... but that's a lot of repetitive code.  Is there a better way?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Car:
    model = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    latest_model_year = Column(Integer)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())  # <- HERE
```

Documentation: [Client-Invoked SQL Expressions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#client-invoked-sql-expressions)

Comment: But when I update an existing row, wouldn't this update the original creation date?  I don't want that.

Comment: No, it's different of `onupdate=func.utc_timestamp()`. See the example in the link.

Comment: Note this solution will evaluate func.now() once and use the value over and over. Perhaps not what is wanted. `default=dt.datetime.now' worked for me.

Comment: @Jaxor24, are you really sure? `func.now()` doesn't return a datetime value but a function that will be evaluate later.